# Angular custom directive on number input needs access to parent reactive form - FormGroup and FormContols

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

I wrote an Angular custom directive that adds some custom buttons to a number input to `stepUp()` and `stepDown()` the value of the input. The directive code looks like this (I have reduced the code).

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[numberControls]'
})
export class NumberControlsDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createStuctureAndControls();
  }

  createStuctureAndControls(): void {
    const parent = this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode;
    // okay, create the container div
    const containerElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    // now let's create a row to contain everything
    const firstRowElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    // let's put the original input in the first row div
    this.renderer.appendChild(firstRowElement, this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    // add the row to the container
    this.renderer.appendChild(containerElement, firstRowElement);
    // add the controls
    const controlsElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const firstControl = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const secondControl = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    // now put some content in the controls
    firstControl.innerHTML = '-'; // to decrease value
    secondControl.innerHTML = '+'; // to increase
    // add click events  
    firstControl.addEventListener('click', this.onClickDecrease.bind(this));
    secondControl.addEventListener('click', this.onClickIncrease.bind(this));
    // put the controls into the controlsElement
    this.renderer.appendChild(controlsElement, firstControl);
    this.renderer.appendChild(controlsElement, secondControl);
    // not put it in the first row
    this.renderer.appendChild(firstRowElement, controlsElement);
    // append to the dom
    this.renderer.appendChild(parent, containerElement);
    // Remove the directive attribute (not really necessary, but just to be clean)
    this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'numberControls');
  }

  /**
   * Method to increase value
   */
  onClickDecrease(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.stepDown();
  }

  /**
   * Method to decrease value
   */
  onClickIncrease(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.stepUp();
  }
}
```

Now I add the directive to a reactive form, this is what it looks like in my html file.

```
<form [formGroup]="myReactiveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="number" formControlName="numberOne" numberControls>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I click one of the controls to stepUp or stepDown the value of the input is updated, however the Reactive Form where I use the directive isn't updated. I need the form to be marked as touched or dirty. I am unsure how I can access the `FormGroup` or `FormControl` that the directive is contained. I have tried using `FormGroupDirective` within the directive code but this doesn't seem to work. Nor does using `NgModel`. I am a bit confused how I can update the parent form (if it exists). Does anyone have any idea or information on how I can get access to the parent form in my directive. Thanks in advance.

If my explanation is bad or confusing please say so and I shall reword.

Comment: You can simply pass the formGroup and formControl value as an `Input()` property to the directive. On step up and down you can use `patchValue()` or `setValue()` to set the data.

Comment: I did as you said and that resolved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can inject [NgControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl) inside numberControlsDirective to get parent form instance.

**Try this**

```
export class NumberControlsDirective 
      constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private ngControl:NgControl,
        private renderer: Renderer2) {
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.ngControl.control.parent);
        this.createStuctureAndControls();
      }
    
    }
```